# Remove last blank row in CSV using Logic App

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, azure-logic-apps

I have a CSV file stored in SFTP where the last row is a blank, so the data looks like this in text:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
,,
```

How can I use Logic App to remove that final row and then save it in BLOB? I have the following but will need some extra steps before the BLOB creation I think.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the same sample here is my Logic app

[image]

In `Compose_2` it takes the index of the last empty item. Below is the expression that I used to retrieve the lastIndex.

```
lastIndexOf(variables('Sample'),'\n')
```

Then in `Compose_3` I'm selecting the one which I wanted

```
substring(variables('Sample'),0,outputs('Compose_2'))
```

**Here is the Final Result**

[image]

**NOTE:-**
Make sure you remove an extra ' \ ' been attached to '\n' in the code view at the `Compose_2`.

[image]

So the final Compose_2 looks like

```
lastIndexOf(variables('Sample'),'
')
```

---

#### **Updated Answer**

If the received data is coming from CSV then you can use the `take()` expression you retrieve the wanted rows. Here are a few screen shots for detailed explanation:-

[image]

[image]

Below is the expression in the compose connector

```
take(outputs('Split_To_Get_Rows'),sub(length(outputs('Split_To_Get_Rows')),1))
```

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda-MT, unfortunately your solution does not work, as `lastIndexOf(variables('Sample'),'\n')` is returning -1. I'm assuming I need to initialise a variable called "Sample" and set the value to be File Content of the CSV file first. I tried this and setting the type to be String which returns -1, so I tried to set the type to Array but got this error instead: `"The variable 'Sample' of type 'Array' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'String'. The variable 'Sample' only supports values of types 'Array'."`

Comment: @tommyhmt Can you please add the actual data that you are trying to remove the last row? Also what is its type, Becuase As you said it is stored in a text file I have considered it to be a string. If it is array then the expression will be different

Comment: @tommyhmt Please check the updated Answer!